# mySQL select ID edit Column

Tags: php, mysql

My table is named `users`. I have a column named `ID` and `module`. Using mySQL syntax how can i say 'get the column id that equals 3 and update the column module to increment from its original number plus 1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update users set module = module + 1 where id = 3;
```

Comment: Is your database case-insensitive?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't super-clear, but is this what you want?!

```
UPDATE users
SET module = module + 1
WHERE ID = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE users
SET module = module + 1
WHERE ID = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UDPATE users
SET module = module + 1
WERE ID = 3
```

What is it, homework?
:-)

Answer (score 1):

```
"UPDATE users SET module = module + 1 WHERE id=3";
```

That should get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To do it in MySQL:

```
UPDATE myDB.users
SET module = module + 1
WHERE ID = 3
```

Do you need to know how to do this with php as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update `users` set `module` = `module` + 1 where `id` = '3';
```